# Prove that there is a $u\in V$, such that $<u,v_i>$ is greater than zero, for every $i \in {\{1,..,m\}}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly independent list in $V$. Prove that there exists a vector $u\in V$ such that $\langle u,v_i\rangle$ is greater than zero for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Attempt: Suppose $v_1,..,v_m$ are linearly independent and let $\dim V = n$.
If $m=n$, then $v_1,..,v_m$ is a basis for $V$ and any $u \in V$ can be expressed as $u = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_mv_m$, for some scalars. 
Then 
\begin{align}
\langle u,v_i\rangle &= \langle a_1v_1 + ...+ a_mv_m, v_i\rangle\\ 
&= \langle a_1v_1, v_i\rangle +\cdots +\langle a_mv_m,v_i\rangle\\
&= a_1\langle v_1,v_i\rangle + \cdots +a_m\langle v_m,v_i\rangle\\
&= a_i\langle v_i,v_i\rangle
\end{align} 
is greater than zero, for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Can someone please give me some feedback? Thank you.

Comment: Just because the $v_i 's$ are linearly independent, doesn't mean that $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = 0 $ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: I am not saying their dot product is zero, but greater than zero.

Comment: $(1,2), (1,-2)$ are linearly independent vectors, but their dot product is negative.

Comment: So any ideas for this problem?

Comment: Geometric intuition makes me think that the $u=v_1 + \dots + v_m$ should work.

Comment: so assume all the scalars are one?

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that having a positive dot product means the angle between the two vectors in acute. The sum of two vectors is a sort of "average" of them and so should cut the angle in half. Of course, this geometric intuition falls apart in arbitrary vector spaces, but I feel like the same $u$ should work in general.

Comment: so $<u, v_i> = <v_1+...+v_m, v_i> = <v_i,v_i> $ greater than zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_mv_m$ and consider the equations

$$
\langle u,v_i\rangle = a_1\langle v_1,v_i\rangle + \cdots + a_m\langle v_m,v_i\rangle = b_i
$$

for $i = 1,\ldots,m$. These equations give rise to the linear system $Ga = b$, where $G_{ij} = \langle v_i,v_j\rangle$ for $1 \leq i,j\leq m$ is the Gram matrix. Since $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are linearly independent the Gram matrix is invertible and hence there exists a unique solution to $Ga = b$ for all right-hand sides $b$. So, choose $b$ to have strictly positive elements, solve for $a$, and let $u = a_1v_1+\cdots+a_mv_m$. By construction $\langle u,v_i\rangle = b_i > 0$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$.